# vue 3 composition api props function Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a prop called [sortSearch](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails4-springsecurity-rest-vue3-composition-typescript/blob/main/client/src/components/country/table/CountryTable.vue#L133) which is a function or callback from parent caller.

```
type SortSearchInterface = (
 currentSort: string,
 currentSortDir: string
) => void;

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    //sortSearch: {
    //type: Function as PropType<(currentSort: string, currentSortDir: string)=> void>
    // type: Function as PropType<SortSearchInterface>|undefined
    // }
    sortSearch: Function as PropType<SortSearchInterface>,
  },
```

When [attempting to call this function](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails4-springsecurity-rest-vue3-composition-typescript/blob/main/client/src/components/country/table/CountryTable.vue#L163) I get the following error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'`:

```
     // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.Vetur(2722)
      //props.sortSearch(s, state.currentSortDir);
```

With my brief googling found very limited examples / documentation on this and any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark this prop as required:

```
  props: {
    sortSearch: {
      type: Function as PropType<SortSearchInterface>,
      required: true
    },
  },
```

Comment: Just to confirm that this has worked, thanks,  interesting issue and fix, not quite sure how setting something to required = true translates to possibly undefined. It kind of starts to make questionable sense as in you have to question does it make sense

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Vue props without `required: true` are optional - ie. the value can be `undefined`...